# Kernel Panic - Can't find root filesystem / error mounting /dev/root

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, kernel-panic

From here: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_kernel_problems#Can.27t_find_root_filesystem_.2F_error_mounting_.2Fdev.2Froot

> A lot of these bugs end up being a broken initrd due to bugs in
>   mkinitrd.
>
> Get the user to attach their initrd for their kernel to the
>   bz, and also their /etc/modprobe.conf, or have them examine the
>   contents themselves if they are capable of that.
>
> Picking apart the initrd of a working and failing kernel and doing a diff of the init script can reveal clues. To take apart an initrd, do the following ..

```
mkdir initrd   
 cd initrd/   
 gzip -dc /boot/initrd-2.6.23-0.104.rc3.fc8.img | cpio -id
```

I wish to understand what exactly is being done here.
What has `initrd` to do with anything?
Where are we supposed to create the directory `initrd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) (short for “initial RAM drive”) is a filesystem that's mounted when the Linux kernel boots, before the “real” root filesystem. This filesystem is loaded into memory by the bootloader, and remains in memory until the real boot. The kernel executes the program `/linuxrc` on the initrd; its job is to mount the real root, and when `/linuxrc` terminates the kernel runs `/sbin/init`.

A bug somewhere in the initrd can explain why the system doesn't boot. So the document you link to recommends that you compare your initrd with an official one if you have trouble booting.

In the provided instructions, `initrd` is just some temporary directory, you can call it `anisha_initrd` or `fred` if you like. The initrd is stored in the file `/boot/initrd-SOMETHING.img` as a gzipped [cpio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) archive; the instructions unpack that archive in the temporary directory you created. After unpacking, you can compare it with an official initrd (unpack the official initrd and run a command like `diff -ru /path/to/official_initrd /path/to/anisha_initrd`).

Answer (score 3):

The steps you referred to describe *how to examine* an initrd image, i.e., how to unpack (via `gzip` and `cpio`) the `initrd-2.6.23-0.104.rc3.fc8.img` file into a directory (`initrd/` here, created anywhere, with `mkdir`).  It's just a step towards finding the problem, no solution in itself.

Comment: Thanks, What is an initrd image? in brief, if you can. :)

Comment: "initrd" is short for "initial ram disk", it's an image the Linux kernel loads into memory as one step of the boot process, for example to load modules that might be needed (e.g. "LVM") -- AFAIK; better look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) `:)`